# Multiple transactions among one of them calls addToBackstack

Tags: android, android-fragments

Let's say I have 4 fragments A, B, C, D. A opens B, B opens C, C opens D through `replace` method `transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main, fragment)`
When I replace fragment A with fragment B, I call `transaction.addToBackStack(fragment.tag)`
When replacing B with C and then C with D, addToBackStack is not called.

`A scheme: A -> replace + addToBstk -> B -> replace -> C -> replace -> D`

**I am doing this because I want that whenever I click back from fragments B, C, D to have fragment A displayed.**

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/fragmentmanager#perform) states

```
If you don't call addToBackStack() when you perform a transaction that removes a fragment, then the removed fragment is destroyed when the transaction is committed, and the user cannot navigate back to it. If you do call addToBackStack() when removing a fragment, then the fragment is only STOPPED and is later RESUMED when the user navigates back.
```

However on transaction B-C, the fragment B is not destroyed, even the transaction is not added to backstack. B is destroyed when pressing back from fragments C or D, but D is not destroyed so A will overlap with D instead of having just A.

Why does this happen and how can I achieve the desired behaviour?

```
public fun transitionFragment(fragment: Fragment, addToBackstack: Boolean) {
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main, fragment);
        if (addToBackstack) {
            transaction.addToBackStack(fragment.tag)
        }
        transaction.commit()
    }

I call this function with:
transitionFragment(fragA, false), transitionFragment(fragB, true), transitionFragment(fragC, false), transitionFragment(fragD, false)
```

Comment: You've to add A fragment to the back stack... others just replace and commit it.. Can you add sample code here?

Comment: Are you using navigation components?

Comment: I am not using navigation components.
Updated question with sample code

Comment: A should be true other fragments false

Comment: If I do like that, when I click back I will see only fragment D. Because if you add A with true, and press back from whatever other fragment, it will first revert A's transaction (which will cause the main blank activity to appear) and the current fragment will stay because `back` only reverts last transaction which is the one where you add A. Mention: transitionFragment is called from MainActivity

Comment: Whenever back press you wan to see A mean you've to add backstack only for the A fragment... Other fragment replace enough... If you're in B,C Or D once you press back A will appear... If it's not working you're doing somewhere wrongly

Comment: Think like that: transitionFragment(A, true) means replace current fragment from main activity which is null with A.  When you call addToBackStack you eanble reverting this transaction on further `back` press. Reverting this transaction means undo replacing null fragment with A, which mans showing the blank activity. You call addToBackStack when you want the fragment to be replaced to be shown on back press. Do you understand? :-) Please provide me a code sample if you think I am wrong. Thanks for your involvement!